# Finding end of string: *s++ VS *s then s++

Tags: c, pointers, postfix-operator

I'm writing a simple string concatenation program.

The program works the way I have posted it. However, I first wrote it using the following code to find the end of the string:

```
while (*s++)
    ;
```

However, that method didn't work. The strings I passed to it weren't copied correctly. Specifically, I tried to copy "abc" to a char[] variable that held "\0".

From reading the C K&R book, it looks like it should work. That compact form should take the following steps.

1. *s is compared with '\0'
2. s points to the next address

So why doesn't it work? I am compiling with gcc on Debian.

I found that this version does work:

```
strncat(char *s, const char *t, int n)
{
    char *s_start = s;

    while (*s)
        s++;

    for ( ; n > 0 && *t; n--, s++, t++)
        *s = *t;

    *(s++) = '\0';

    return s_start;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For future reference "didn't work." is *not* a helpful description of the failure mode. How did the result differ from what you expected?

Comment: on unrelated note, whenever doing non-obvious stuff, use parenthesis. You may remember now ++ is above * in operator priority table, but after 7 hours of coding straight you really, really begin to wonder whether *s++; means *(s++); or (*s)++;

Comment: just as a side note: take another name for that function. This is not how strncat works.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

After the end of `while (*s++);`, `s` points to *the character after* the null terminator. Take that into account in the code that follows.

Answer (score 6):

The problem is that

```
 while (*s++)
     ;
```

Always Increments s, even when s is zero (*s is false)

```
 while (*s)
    s++;
```

only increments s when *s is nonzero

so the first one will leave s pointing to first character *after* the first \0, while the second one will leave s pointing to the first \0.

Answer (score 4):

There is difference. In the first case, s will point to the position after '\0', while the second stops right at '\0'.

Answer (score 2):

As John Knoeller said, at the end of the run it'll s will point to the location *after* the NULL. *BUT* There is no need to sacrifice performance for the correct solution.. Take a look for yourself:

`while (*s++); --s;`

Should do the trick.

Comment: Don't you mean to say `while (*s++); --s;`?

Comment: Whoops! Thanks for catching that.. I was on my way out of the door to work when I posted that in a hurry :)

Answer (score 0):

In addition what has been said, note that in C it is technically illegal for a pointer to point to unallocated memory, even if you don't dereference it.  So be sure to fix your program, even if it appears to work.

Comment: the first location after an array is specifically allowed to be pointed to (to allow comparisons with pointers in the array) so this isn't a problem

Comment: Addressing one item past the end of an array is a special case that the standard explicitly defines.  Here's a topic that contains a discussion about it:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/988158/take-the-address-of-a-one-past-the-end-array-element-via-subscript-legal-by-the