# copy all the array into new array without vectors C++

Tags: c++, avr, avr-gcc

```
int led_p1[8] = {0x01, 0x02, 0x04, 0x08, 
                 0x10, 0x20, 0x40, 0x80};
int led_p2[8] = {0x81, 0x42, 0x24, 0x18,
                 0x18, 0x24, 0x42, 0x81};
int led_p3[8] = {0xFF, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00,
                 0xFF, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00};

int led_pattern[8] = {};
int pattern_idx = 0;



// select pattern for now
switch(pattern_idx)
{
    case 0: 
        led_pattern = led_p1;
        pattern_idx++;
        break;
    case 1: 
        led_pattern = led_p2;
        pattern_idx++;
        break;
    case 2: 
        led_pattern = led_p3;
        pattern_idx = 0;
        break;
}
```

I tried doing the above, I am going to loop round idx, copying a new sequence into the led_pattern, then loop round that, come back, get the next one.

I found a method to pass a whole array using a vector here;
[C++: copy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3598859/c-copy-array)

But vectors (I believe) don't work on the compiler I am using (avr-gcc/c++)

How can I implement this within C++? I know in python the below would work, I can assign an array to another variable, and it "clones" it.

Thanks

Comment: I don't understand; why can't you do `led_pattern[0] = led_p1[0]` .. etc?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you really need to copy into `led_pattern`? Are you going to change the contents? If it's essentially const, why don't you declare `led_pattern` as a pointer to an int? That would be much more efficient as you'll just be pointing to one of the three existing arrays rather than copying them.

If not, use `memcpy` to copy from one of your three arrays into `led_pattern`

Comment: I think I may try this along with the others, as to be honest, yes I do just want to use and not modify the values.Thanks

Comment: +1 for identifying X, not solving Y, in [the XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Great read on the XY problem, never heard of it. You learn something new every day! (well may two things in my case!) Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 3):

Replace this line that doesn't do what you want:

```
led_pattern = led_p1;
```

With any one of these that will, in descending order of preference.

```
std::copy(led_p1, led_p1 + 8, led_pattern);

memcpy(led_pattern, led_p1, sizeof led_p1);

for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++) led_pattern[i] = led_p1[i];
```

Comment: Or better yet, use [Boost.Array](http://www.boost.org/libs/array/) which has proper copy semantics out of the box.

Comment: Or better, better yet, use `std::array` if your compiler supports it.

Comment: Although, if "vectors don't work on the compiler I am using," it is kind of hard to know what will.

Comment: It's possible that vectors don't work because exceptions are disabled; if so, `array<>` should still be fine.

Comment: @Robᵩ vectors may not be supported because the platform does not have a heap implementation, and hence no dynamic memory allocation. But `std::array` should work if that's the limitation.

Comment: Your `memcpy` will not work. sizeof led_p1 will give you the size of a pointer instead of an array.

Comment: @texasbruce No it won't, it'll return `8 * sizeof(int)`

Comment: @Rob I made a mistake then. sizeof is quite different in C++ than in C

Comment: I believe it does have a heap, and that certain elements like vectors and inheritance, work very poorly on 8 bit MCU's. I will have a go at copy first, then memcpy (I know this should work as C is rock solid on the AVR) I was hoping to avoid a loop, and sorry guys I do not think I can use anything out of the standard library, ideally I shouldn't have to anyway! Thanks everyone for all the information to work on.

Comment: @user1337077 - Seriously consider the advice to make `led_pattern` a `const int*` pointer that variously points at `led_p1`, `led_p2` and `led_p3`. That is certainly better advice, assuming it is possible in your application.

Comment: @texasbruce: sizeof is not different in C++ and C.

Comment: @texasbruce - S'okay, mistakes happen. I hope I didn't sound too harsh. You should know, however, that you'll get [the same answer in C](http://ideone.com/DLRgD).

Comment: Yes, I have tried the pointer and it works. This is exactly what I wanted to accomplish. Thanks.

Comment: @Rob Although it smells like sarcasm, I still take it. I thought `sizeof(array)` is the same as `sizeof(pointer)` because they are basically the same thing, but it turns out I am wrong. On my 64bit computer, `sizeof(10 chars array) is 10`, and `sizeof(pointer to this char array) is 8 (8 is for 8 bytes = 64bits)`.

Answer (score 3):

If I'm reading the OP correctly, you do not want a deep copy, but want to switch what array is being used for the LEDs.  So you would make a pointer that you can switch among arrays, like so:

```
int led_p1[8] = {0x01, 0x02, 0x04, 0x08, 
                 0x10, 0x20, 0x40, 0x80};
int led_p2[8] = {0x81, 0x42, 0x24, 0x18,
                 0x18, 0x24, 0x42, 0x81};
int led_p3[8] = {0xFF, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00,
                 0xFF, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00};

int *led_pattern = led_p1; //Starting point
int pattern_idx = 0;

// select pattern for now
switch(pattern_idx)
{
    case 0: 
        led_pattern = led_p1;
        pattern_idx++;
        break;
    case 1: 
        led_pattern = led_p2;
        pattern_idx++;
        break;
    case 2: 
        led_pattern = led_p3;
        pattern_idx = 0;
        break;
}
```

So now you can switch `led_pattern` to point at whichever `led_p*` array you're currently using.

Comment: +1 for identifying OP's underlying problem, rather than (merely) answering his question.

Answer (score 2):

A usual approach would be to use std::copy(). std::copy takes two iterators that denote the start and the end of the sequence to copy and a third parameter, as the destination:

```
std::copy( &led_p1[ 0 ], &led_p1[ sizeof(led_p1) / sizeof(led_p1[ 0 ]) ], &led_pattern[ 0 ])
```

Where the expression sizeof(led_p1) / sizeof(led_p1[ 0 ]) evaluates to 8, the number of elements in your array. Instead of using 3 distinct array with you LED pattern, you could use an array with 3 arrays and iterate over this 3 arrays.

Comment: FYI: if you have C++11 available, the first two args can be `std::begin(led_p1), std::end(led_p1)`.

Comment: @Robᵩ end even, if you do not have C++11 available, thous functions are so handy, that I've putt them in every tool box on every project I've worked on ;-) It's just a one liner each.

Answer (score 1):

To make a deep copy, you have to copy every single value in the first array to the new array. Instead of just assigning the old pointer to the new one, do a for loop on the number of elements in the array and assign each one to the new copy.

Answer (score 1):

To make a hard copy in the memory level, you might want to use the old C function: `memcpy`

```
memcpy (led_pattern,led_p1, 8 * sizeof(int));
```

`8` should be replaced by array size if it is different.

Function explanation:
www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/memcpy/

`#include <string.h>` should also be used.(Edited as Prætorian said)

Comment: If you `#include <cstring>` you should qualify function call as `std::memcpy`. To call it as `memcpy`, include `<string.h>` instead. Or best of all, since the question is tagged C++, use `std::copy`.