# copying an array into a vector

Tags: c++, vector, stdvector

I have written a small program:

```
void showrecord()
{
     char *a[]={ "O_BILLABLE_ACCOUNT","O_CUSTOMER_TYPE_INDICATOR",
                 "O_A_PARTY_MSISDN_ID","O_A_PARTY_EQUIPMENT_NUMBER",
                 "O_A_PARTY_IMSI","O_A_PARTY_LOCATION_INFO_CELL_ID",
                 ...  
               };

     vector<std::string> fields(a,a+75);

     cout<<"done!!!"<<endl;
}

int main()
{
     showrecord();
}
```

I have array of string literals and i want them to be copied into a vector.
I did not find any other easy way to do it :(.Or if there is any direct way to initialize the vector without using the array ,that would be very much helpful.
This is dumping the core after i run the executable on unix.
It gives me a warning though like :

```
Warning 829: "test.cpp", line 12 
# Implicit conversion of string literal to 'char *' is deprecated.
D_TYPE","O_VARCHAR_5","O_VARCHAR_6","O_VARCHAR_7","O_VARCHAR_8","O_VARCHAR_9"};
```

But the same code is running fine on windows without any problem.
I am using the compiler aCC on HPUX.

Please help!
**EDIT**
below is teh stacktrace of the dump.

```
(gdb) where
#0  0x6800ad94 in strlen+0xc () from /usr/lib/libc.2
#1  0xabc0 in std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>+0x20 ()
#2  0xae9c in std<char const **,std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>> *,std::allocator<std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>>>::uninitialized_copy+0x60 ()
#3  0x9ccc in _C_init_aux__Q2_3std6vectorXTQ2_3std12basic_stringXTcTQ2_3std11char_traitsXTc_TQ2_3std9allocatorXTc__TQ2_3std9allocatorXTQ2_3std12basic_stringXTcTQ2_3std11char_traitsXTc_TQ2_3std9allocatorXTc____XTPPCc_FPPCcT118_RW_is_not_integer+0x2d8
    ()
#4  0x9624 in showrecord () at test.cpp:13
#5  0xdbd8 in main () at test.cpp:21
```

Comment: what's this `uninitialized_copy` in the stack trace? Are you showing the compete program that causes the crash? Also, I would try this in gcc, if it works than you may have a problem with aCC (it's quite old, isn't it? HPUX is phasing out AFAIK)

Comment: @davka: that is an implementation detail of the library, I have seen functions with that name in STL implementation to copy construct from a set of iterators into some uninitialized memory.

Comment: @davka `uninitialized_copy` is probably being called by the constructor of `std::vector`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why 75?

Change

```
vector<std::string> fields(a,a+75);
```

to

```
vector<std::string> fields(a, a + sizeof a / sizeof *a);
```

---

There's no arguably 'better' way to initialize your vector for C++03, but for C++0x you have access to a more convenient syntax, dispensing with the C array:

```
std::vector<std::string> fields {
    "O_BILLABLE_ACCOUNT",
    // ...
};
```

Comment: I'd prefer `fields(&a[0], &a[sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0])])` for readability.

Comment: Because the array contains 75 strings.and it is fixed.will never change

Comment: @Rahul Have you tried applying my fix? The code you provided us runs without a hitch with it. This kind of hardcoded value is a maintenance timebomb and this one seems to have gone off before said maintenance.

Comment: @Rahul: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)#Unnamed_numerical_constants

Comment: @Kay: I think `&a[sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0])]` yields undefined behavior because you dereference an pointer to an invalid object.

Comment: @ybungalobill It's an explicit special case in both C and C++, it's equivalent to `a + sizeof a / sizeof *a` **and** is not considered dereferencing (unlike the normal case).

Comment: @Kay Technically, that is undefined behavior, since it involves `a[onePastEnd]`, which is undefined behavior.  (By definition, `a[onePastEnd]` is the same as `*(a + onePastEnd)`, which is a dereference.)

Comment: @Luc: Nope, it's only a special case in C99. In C++, [it is technically undefined behavior](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3144904/).

Comment: For compile-time constant array sizes you could/should use a template to deduce the array size as in mloskot's answer below, so you don't have to divide any sizes.

Answer (score 4):

Try `const char* a[]` instead of `char* a[]`. String literals are of type `const char*`, not `char*`, and hence you get the warning.

Comment: You are right.Warnings are gone now ..but the core dump still persists

Comment: Well, actually, literals are `const char[]`, which decays to `const char*`

Answer (score 2):

Here is possible solution which IMO is a little bit more general - uses reusable function that works with string arrays of any size:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

template <typename Array, std::size_t Size>
std::vector<std::string> make_vector(Array (&ar)[Size])
{
    std::vector<std::string> v(ar, ar + Size);
    return v;
}

int main()
{
     char const* a[] = { "Aa","Bb", "Cc","Dd", "Ee","Ff" };

     // copy C-array to vector
     std::vector<std::string> fields = make_vector(a);

     // test
     std::copy(fields.begin(), fields.end(),
               std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, "\n"));
}
```

Comment: You can even remove the explicit `v`, just `return std::vector...`. Also, you could make a second version which takes an explicit size argument to accommodate arrays that aren't of compile-time constant size.

Comment: @Kerrek SB - yes, further templatization / improvements are possible or even advised. I left it as an exercice to the OP