# Is accessing data outside an array incorrect if you don't use it?

Tags: c++, c, arrays, undefined-behavior

In an algorithm I'm writing, I can have the following (simplified of course)

```
int a[3] = {1,2,3};
int b = a[3];
```

when the index used to fill `b` overflows, I *never* use the value of b. Is the code still incorrect? Do I have to make an explicit boundary check?

Comment: The answer is already given, but I can highly recommend this series of blog posts concerning undefined behavior in C: ([part 1](http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know.html), [part 2](http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know_14.html), [part 3](http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know_21.html)). It also addresses situations where you can get bitten badly by relying on this kind of undefined behavior (with a motivating example from the linux kernel (in part 2)).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This code has Undefined Behavior whether or not you use `b`. Why? Because `a[3]` is equivalent to `*(a+3)` by definition. And here's a quote from the standard that proved that `*(a+3)` is in itself undefined, regardless of whether the value is stored, used, or left alone.

> When an expression that has integral
>   type is added to or subtracted from a
>   pointer, the result has the type of
>   the pointer operand. If the pointer
>   operand points to an element of an
>   array object, and the array is large
>   enough, the result points to an
>   element offset from the original
>   element such that the difference of
>   the subscripts of the resulting and
>   original array elements equals the
>   integral expression. In other words,
>   if the expression P points to the i-th
>   element of an array object, the
>   expressions (P)+N (equivalently,
>   N+(P)) and (P)-N (where N has the
>   value n) point to, respectively, the
>   i+n-th and i−n-th elements of the
>   array object, provided they exist.
>   Moreover, if the expression P points
>   to the last element of an array
>   object, the expression (P)+1 points
>   one past the last element of the array
>   object, and if the expression Q points
>   one past the last element of an array
>   object, the expression (Q)-1 points to
>   the last element of the array object.
>   If both the pointer operand and the
>   result point to elements of the same
>   array object, or one past the last
>   element of the array object, the
>   evaluation shall not produce an
>   overﬂow; otherwise, the behavior is
>   undeﬁned.

Comment: @Kerrek: Woops, read that as "is the code still **correct**?".

Comment: "or one past the last element of the array object, the evaluation shall not produce an overﬂow" --> does this mean the code is correct if the index is equal to the size of the array?

Comment: @static_rtti: Yes, but only if you do it with pointer arithmetic (`(a + 3)`) and you shall not dereference the pointer you get (which automatically happens with `a[3]`).

Answer (score 3):

Still incorrect, still undefined behaviour. Do the bounds check.

```
int b = *(a + 3); // dereferencing beyond the array bound.
```

Comment: @Downvoter: I'd be pleased if you could tell me how to improve this answer!

Comment: Someone obviously disagrees and downvoted several answers.  :-)

Answer (score 3):

Reading `a[3]` already causes undefined behaviour. As undefined behaviour is never locally limited, this can already lead to your harddisk drive being formatted or your computer emerging to a giant, flesh-eating zombie.

In reality, it will usually just work. But it's easy to make up a case where the end of the array marks the end of a mapped memory region, so accessing one element beyond would cause a segmentation fault. This is certainly not the case for an array of `int` on the stack and neither with most heap implementations, but you shouldn't rely on it.

(Whether taking the address of `&a[3]` is undefined behaviour as well [is heavily disputed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3144904/may-i-take-the-address-of-the-one-past-the-end-element-of-an-array).)

Comment: Why is the validity of `&a[3]` disputed? It's the same as `a+3` which is explicitly allowed. Or are you talking about the redundant `&*` at the beginning being a "dereference"?

Comment: @R: If you follow the link, you can read the dispute for yourself.

Comment: R..: I think that's one part, the other is IIRC that in C++, pointers to memory areas not allocated by means of the language are invalid.

Comment: If we're talking about C at least, it should not at all be heavily disputed. &a[3] is perfectly legal because using & on an [] operand does not derefernce anything: "Similarly, if the operand is the result of a [] operator, neither the & operator nor the unary * that is implied by the [] is evaluated and the result is as if the & operator
were removed and the [] operator were changed to a + operator"

Answer (score 2):

It's still incorrect yes, because you access the out-of-bounds memory location to get the value `a[3]` and store it in the variable `b`.

The fact that you never use `b` could mean that the compiler optimizes out that line of code, so you might not ever see any adverse effects from that line being there.

However, the compiler is not required to do so, and the code itself still has undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

You *are* using the value, by copying it into `b`.

More specifically, dereferencing `(a+3)` is not allowed since the expression `(a+3)` is not a valid pointer... and the *expression* `a[3]` is equivalent to `*(a+3)` (where `a` has decayed to a pointer-expression).

Comment: "and the rvalue `a[3]`..." makes no sense. `a[3]` is not a pointer or an array; it has type `int`.

Comment: R.: ... which is the result of `*(a+3)`. `a[3]` is an _rvalue_ indeed, of type `int`. [edit: actually it's an _lvalue_ ]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is wrong to read `a[3]` which doesn't exits.

Using `b` would be wrong too, but it is already too late.

Comment: `b` is just an int, what's the harm in using it? It has indeterminate value, sure, but it's not memory-incorrect to use it...

Comment: @Kerrek SB `int`s are allowed to have trapping values (and do on some implementations).

Comment: @Kerrek - You cannot read an indeterminate value, it might trap. It doesn't matter here either, as it is already UB before getting to read `b`.

Comment: @James: What's a trapping value, and how does that affect the program flow?

Comment: The actual violation happens before indeterminate values come into play. It's an array bounds violation, and even if you somehow knew there was valid memory after the array (e.g. if it came from `malloc` or a struct), it's then an aliasing violation too if the data at that location is not part of the array of type `int[3]`.

Comment: @Kerrek SB A trapping value is a bit pattern which causes some sort of hardware reaction *when read*, typically a trap, which results in the OS taking over and doing something, typically aborting the program with prejudice.  Thus, a one's complement machine might arrange for all 0 results to be a positive 0, and trap if you read a negative 0.

Comment: @James: Thanks! But would the trap have to happen when reading `a[3]` (suppose it points to a trapping value), or only when later reading `b`?

Comment: @Kerrek The access is undefined behavior; there's no guarantee of a trap on any machine.  But it could occur on just a read, before you do anything with the value.