# (Typecasting to Constant Literal ) Why this output of a C program

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct bar
{
    int data[10];
};


int main(void) {
    printf("%d", ((struct bar*)0)+5);
    return 0;
}
```

Output is 200.
I came across this on some c programming website. Can someone explain me this?

Comment: Why the c++ tag?

Comment: Basically, you're printing the size of 5 `struct bar`s.

Comment: Pointer arithmetic. `sizeof(struct bar)` is 40. Adding X to such a pointer increments the pointer by X*40.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pointer Arithmetic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/394767/pointer-arithmetic)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The zero typecasting confuses me at times. Can you suggest some material on it?

Comment: The type casting just says, "treat this value as a pointer to struct bar". In this case, `0` is not special. You could have made it any value Y in which case the result would be `Y+40*5`.

Comment: Basically a dummy address to which we add the 40*5. Thanks a lot, that helps.

Comment: But 0 is chosen specifically so that we just get the result of the multiplication.

Comment: This is undefined behavior, since `((struct bar*)0)+5` is an address; the line should be: `printf("%p", (void *) ((struct bar*)0)+5));`.

Comment: @Barmar and David Bowling. That helps.

Comment: It is undefined behaviour. Arithmetic on a _null pointer_ is not allowed.

Comment: @kaylum `0` is special in that converting a literal `0` to pointer produces a null pointer. Trying the same with any other integer is implementation-defined behaviour and may trigger exceptions and so on

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Edit:** I am updating based on the comment section.

We understand that arithmetic on **null pointer** is undefined behavior. You can read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15608366/is-performing-arithmetic-on-a-null-pointer-undefined-behavior).

The current code does not specifically use `NULL`. Instead it uses literal `0` which is then casted into **null pointer** with `((struct bar*)0)`. As a result, in this code we have an undefined behavior, as well. If instead of `0`, we had another literal (say `1`), then whether it produces a value (`201`in case of using `1`) or causes an error would be implementation-dependent.

This output (`200`) comes from here: `sizeof(struct bar)` is 40 bytes and a pointer arithmetic is carried out (`5 x 40 = 200`).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The zero typecasting confuses me at times. Can you suggest some material on it?

Comment: See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/offsetof for tool to help with similar games without requiring you to dabble in easily-exploding NULL pointers.

Comment: @AnupBuchke. We have a `NULL` pointer of type `struct bar*`. What matters over hear is its size which is the size of the struct.

Comment: @Arash: You mean a _null pointer_. `NULL` is a macro with a _null pointer constant_, A variable cannot **be** a macro. And there are two reason for undefined behaviour.

Comment: @Olaf Yes, you are right. I should have said *null pointer*. Thanks for pointing that out.