# gcc/g++ and clang: wrong optimization of conditional

Tags: gcc, clang

I have a question about gcc and clang code optimization. This piece of code shows strange behavior. `arr` initialized as `0` in `main`, becomes `sizeof(int)` in `arr_ctor` and becomes `0` in `arr_resize`. So, conditional shouldn't be executed. When compiled with -O2 conditional gets eliminated and `fprintf` executes. However, when using MSVC with /O2 conditional stays presented and code works fine.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int arr_resize(int* arr)
{
    arr--;

    if(arr != nullptr)                      // this conditional shouldn't be removed 
        fprintf(stderr, "arr = %p\n", arr); //

    return 0;
}

int arr_ctor(int* arr)
{
    arr++;
    arr_resize(arr);

    return 0;
}


int main()
{
    int* arr = {};

    arr_ctor(arr);

    return 0;
}
```

Command line:

> gcc main.cpp -o test_gcc -O2 -Wall -Wextra

> clang main.cpp -o test_clang -O2 -Wall -Wextra

Output (gcc):

> arr = (nil)

Output (clang):

> arr = (nil)

Output (MSVC): no output

> 

Assembly shows that conditional was eliminated in GCC and Clang, but presented in MSVC.

GCC (-O2):

```
<...>

arr_resize:

    subq    $8, %rsp

    leaq    -4(%rdi), %rdx
    movq    stderr(%rip), %rdi
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    leaq    .LC0(%rip), %rsi
    call    fprintf@PLT
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    addq    $8, %rsp

    ret

<...>
```

Clang (-O2):

```
<...>

arr_resize:

    pushq   %rax

    leaq    -4(%rdi), %rdx
    movq    stderr@GOTPCREL(%rip), %rax
    movq    (%rax), %rdi
    leaq    .L.str(%rip), %rsi
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    callq   fprintf@PLT
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    popq    %rcx

    retq

<...>
```

MSVC (/O2):

```
<...>

int arr_resize(int *)
    push    rbx
    sub     rsp, 32
    mov     rbx, rcx
    sub     rbx, 4
    je      SHORT $LN4@arr_resize
    mov     ecx, 2
    call    __acrt_iob_func
    mov     rcx, rax
    lea     rdx, OFFSET FLAT:`string'
    mov     r8, rbx
    call    fprintf
$LN4@arr_resize:
    xor     eax, eax
    add     rsp, 32
    pop     rbx
    ret     0

<...>
```

Command line:

> gcc main.cpp -o test.s -S -O2 -Wall -Wextra -fno-exceptions

> clang main.cpp -o test.s -S -O2 -Wall -Wextra -fno-exceptions

MSVC was tested only on godbolt with /O2, because I don't have it. Clang and GCC were tested on godbolt and on my PC.

For comparison, GCC without optimizations:

```
<...>    

arr_resize:
.LFB0:
    pushq   %rbp
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    subq    $16, %rsp
    movq    %rdi, -8(%rbp)
    subq    $4, -8(%rbp)
    cmpq    $0, -8(%rbp)
    je  .L2
    movq    stderr(%rip), %rax
    movq    -8(%rbp), %rdx
    leaq    .LC0(%rip), %rcx
    movq    %rcx, %rsi
    movq    %rax, %rdi
    movl    $0, %eax
    call    fprintf@PLT
.L2:
    movl    $0, %eax
    leave
    ret

<...>
```

Compilators:

> gcc version 11.2.0 (11.2.0 on godbolt)

> clang version 13.0.1 (14.0.0 on godbolt)

> MSVC version 19.31 on godbolt

Is it a bug or am I missing something?

Comment: You are missing something allright, arr is set to null, that's why your code doesn't work, lol.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15608366/is-performing-arithmetic-on-a-null-pointer-undefined-behavior

Comment: In that case `printf` shouldn't be executed, but it is executed.

Comment: Incrementing or decrementing a valid pointer to a valid array element can't  produce a nullptr, so the check is redundant.

Comment: Care to elaborate on that, @user1095108?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are asking 2 questions

- why does the code get eliminated
- why is that printf executed

It gets eliminated becuase arithmetic on a pointer can never yield nullptr. So it gets treated as

```
if(42 == 42) // ie always true
```

Arithmetic on NULL is UB, once you do that all bets are off. printf might happen, might not