# what is pointer past the end of an object means?

Tags: c++

In C++ Primer, Chapter 2, "Variables and Basic Types", it says:

> it is possible for a pointer to an object and a pointer one past the end of a different object to hold the same address.

I'm not a native speaker, and I think that's why I'm a bit confused by the sentence "a pointer one past the end of an object". Would anyone one tell me what it means please?

Comment: `char c[3]; char* p = c + 3;` p is a pointer one past the end of array c

Comment: For any array, get pointer to its last element, and add 1. This will be and a pointer one past the end.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It means that after

```
int a[] = { 1, 2 };
float b;
```

it's possible that `(void *) &a[2] == (void *) &b` may compare as true.

`&a[2]` (or equivalently, `a+2`) is a pointer just past the end of `a`, because the array only contains elements with indices 0 and 1.

Normally, out-of-range array indices are completely invalid (accessing `a[2]` is not allowed, nor is even computing `&a[3]`), but there is a special exception for computing the address just past the end of an array, because as it turned out, that is quite useful, for example when iterating over an array and you need an end value to know when to stop the loop.

Comment: thx man!, that's exactly what i want to know about, but can you explain a bit more on (void *)?, i dont quite get this part of the answer

Comment: Formally, `&a[2]` is undefined behavior.  The only legal way to get a pointer one past the end is `a + 2`.

Comment: @JamesKanze The intent is that it is defined behaviour. C has formally made it defined, and for C++, that intent has explicitly been stated even if the standard doesn't match the intent yet.

Comment: @libra Without a cast to `void *`, you've got a comparison between `int *` and `float *`. I could have used `int b;` as an example, in which case the cast would be unnecessary, but I wanted to highlight that it can happen regardless of type.

Comment: @hvd: That is correct. So, in conclusion, at the present time, _exactly what James said_.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit For a question with the language-lawyer tag, it would be entirely correct. For this question, it's technically correct, but misleading, in my opinion.

Comment: @hvd References, please.  I know that at one time, the C++ committee explicitly decided _not_ to follow C in this (since they didn't want to support syntax for C style arrays which couldn't be emulated by `std::vector`).  They may have changed their mind later, but I've not heard about it.

Comment: @hvd And it's only "sort of" language lawyering, since if the user later replaces `int a[]` with `std::vector<int> a`, he _will_ get an exception if he does `&a[2]` (supposing 2 elements in the vector, and a debugging version of `std::vector`).  This is why the C++ committee didn't adopt the wording from C standard, and intentionally kept it undefined behavior.

Comment: @JamesKanze My reference is [CWG issue 232](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#232). But good point about container classes.

Comment: @hvd Interesting.  One of my references would have been Tom Plum as well (but from a private conversation, about 10 years earlier).  Maybe the committee did change its mind (although the current wording of the standard doesn't reflect it).  (The issue came up before the adoption of the first standard, when it became clear that C was going to add such wording to the next version of their standard.)

Comment: Does `int* ptr = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int)), *ptr2 = ptr + 1;` invoke UB? What about the same in C?

Comment: @CoolGuy In C, that is definitely valid. In C++, there is no object, and off of the top of my head I do not know if this makes it invalid: as it would not compute one-past-the-end-of-an-object, the exception might not apply. Will check in more detail when I can.

Comment: @CoolGuy After checking the standard, I still don't know. For more background: the problem is the same as how after `int* ptr = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int));`, `*ptr = 1;` is invalid, as it assigns to a non-existent object. C++ strictly speaking requires placement new there to create an object, after which the assignment would become valid, and after which `int* ptr2 = ptr + 1;` would become unambiguously valid as well.

Answer (score 14):

Suppose you have an array, `int foo[5] = {1,2,3,4,5};`. It's laid out in memory like this:

```
-----------
|1|2|3|4|5|
-----------
```

It's legal to have a pointer that points to any member of the array; but it's also legal for a pointer to point *one past the end* of the array (usually to signal that it has reached the end of the array when doing an STL algorithm using iterators) - although it isn't legal to dereference that pointer. Like so:

```
-------------
|1|2|3|4|5|?|
-------------
 ^         ^
 |         |
 p         q
```

`p` is a pointer into the array; `q` is a pointer one-past-the-end.

Now, suppose you also have an array `const char bar[3] = "Hi";`. It's possible that the two arrays have been allocated next to each other in memory, like so:

```
<--foo---> <-bar->
-----------------
|1|2|3|4|5|H|i|0|
-----------------
 ^         ^
 |         |
 p         q
```

Then `q` is both a one-past-the-end for `foo`, and also pointing to the physical location for `bar[0]`.

Comment: thank you so much, that's exactly what i want to know,

Comment: one more question, how do i assign a pointer to the one-past-the-end of that array?, like this "int *pi = foo[6]" ?

Comment: @libra: `int* pi = foo+6;` or `int* a = &foo[5], *pi = a+1;` [It is debatable as to whether `int* pi = &foo[6];`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3144917/560648) [is legal/well-defined](http://stackoverflow.com/a/988254/560648).

Answer (score 2):

"one past" means "+1 operation on the pointer". The following code generates:

```
0x7ffffcf6a848
0x7ffffcf6a84c
0x7ffffcf6a84c
```

As you can see, the address of "one past a", i.e., `&a + 1` is the same as `&b`.

```
    int a = 2; 
    int b = 3;
    cout<< &a << endl << &a + 1 << endl << &b <<endl;
```

Comment: No it doesn't. It means "+1 operation on the pointer such that you are no longer within the bounds of the data it points to, but only by one element".

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit The whole sentence in the question, i.e., "one past the end of ..." is what you said in the comment. I just answered the meaning of "one past". It literally means "+1 operation on pointer". :-)

Comment: No, again, it literally doesn't. "One past" means you are beyond the underlying object by one. Any arbitrary +1 operation is an _increment_; you could call it "one up" but nobody else does! `int ar[3] = {}; int* ptr = ar; ar+1; // NOT "one past"!`

Comment: Haha I was just listening to "Let It Go". Weird.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit That ONLY depends how you understand "past" in english. One day past 2/12/13. Therefore, in my view, you are just talking about English not programming in C++.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit ar+1 is one past the previous value of ar. Isn't it? This is just about ENGLISH.

Comment: I know it is about English, and as someone who has lived in _England_ for several decades I am sitting here telling you that your English is wrong: that is not the commonly accepted meaning of "one past" in this context.