# Example of how it is possible for a pointer to an object and a pointer one past the end of a different object to hold same address

Tags: c++, pointers, one-past-end-pointer

I am learning C++ using the book *C++ Primer by Stanley*. In particular when I started reading about pointers, I came across the following statement made in the book:

> Note that it is possible for a pointer to an object and a pointer one past the end of a different object to hold
> the same address.

---

Now my question is that can someone give some example of what they mean by the above statement. I mean, some example will help me understand this(the above statement) better. I am a beginner and so could not directly understand what they meant by it. An example will certainly help me clarify the above rule/statement.

Comment: When you have an array of objects, the next object starts one after the last ends

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/d4j7GfM18, note this isn't specified by the standard and just happens to be how GCC has laid out the variables

Comment: It can also happen randomly if you have two global variables and the compiler/linker put them next to each other in memory (but you cannot count on that) or if they are placed next to each other in a larger object or struct

Comment: That would simply happen when two objects are adjacent in memory. Either because you forced that, or simply because they happened to be allocated that way.

Comment: See exact duplicate: [what is pointer past the end of an object means?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21850108/what-is-pointer-past-the-end-of-an-object-means)

Comment: Is "immediately after" easier to understand than "one past the end"?  Do you understand that objects can have addresses?  Do you understand that one object's address might be after another object's address?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Imagine the following placement in memory (int and double are both expected to be 64 bits wide):

| Address | Object | sub-object | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0x1000 | a: array of 4 ints | 1st elt(a[0]) | 1 |
| 0x1008 | " | 2nd elt (a[1]) | 2 |
| 0x1010 | " | 3rd elt (a[2]) | 3 |
| 0x1018 | " | 4th elt (a[3]) | 4 |
| 0x1020 | d: double |  | 1.5 |

It could be obtained for example (up to an address translation) from this declarations:

```
int a[] = {1, 2, 3, 4};
double d = 1.5;
```

if the compiler decided to store the elements in declaration order in memory.

In this example, `&a[4]` would point one past the end of array `a` and would have value `0x1020`, which would also be the value of `&d`. Yet `a` and `d` are totally unrelated objects (except being placed close to one other in this example)

Answer (score 2):

You can increment a pointer to an object by one. Even if this does not make the pointer point anywhere. For example:

```
int a = 42;
int* ptr = &a;
++ptr;
```

Now `ptr` does point "one past" `a`. Note that `++ptr` is somewhat special. Usually pointer arithmetics only works inside arrays. You may not arbitrarily increment `ptr`. But objects can be considered as a 1-element array and incrementing `ptr` once is allowed.

How two objects are layed out in memory is up to the implementation. Typically objects defined after each other are next to each other in memory. And it is possible (but not guaranteed and code that relies on this is bound to break) for the following to print the same address twice:

```
 int a = 42;
 int b = 42;
 int* ptr_a = &a;
 int* ptr_b = &b;   // address of b
 ++ptr_a;           // one past the address of a
 std::cout << ptr_a << " "  << ptr_b;
```

However, without context this quote is not very enlightening. It merely says that two pointers may hold the same address.

This "one past" thing gets more interesting when you consider arrays, because a "one past the end pointer" is often used to denote the end of an array. For example iterators of `std::vector` can be just bare pointers and the `end` iterator points to one past the last element in the array. This is interesting for iteration, because you can use the `end` for the stop condition:

```
 int x[42]{};
 int* begin = &x[0];
 int* end = begin + 42;
 for ( ; begin != end; ++begin) {
      // do something with *begin
 }
```

`end` does not point to an element in the array, but one past the last element. Note that `end` is never dereferenced, as the iteration stops when the `end` is reached. Note that this loop is just for illustration, you wouldnt actually write code like this.