# Copy section of an array into a std::vector in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, copy

Hello im wondering if its possible to copy a section of an array whilst initializing a vector.

For example I have tried

```
UINT16 myarray[] = { 0,1,2,3,4,5,6, ..., n };
std::vector<UINT16> myvect(myarray[3], myarray[3] + 16);
```

This kind of works however I seem to get more data than i intended.  Is this the correct usage?

Comment: So you want to copy indexes `[3, 19)`?

Comment: You need to pass addresses, so `myarray + 3, myarray + 19` seems like it would work. Better to identifier your pointers though.

Comment: Or take the addresses like this: `std::vector<UINT16> myvect(&myarray[3], &myarray[3 + 16])`

Comment: @Galik: assuming size is greater than 19...

Comment: As François Andrieux and Jarod42 stated, it was a matter of using integer offsets to select which part of the array i wanted copied.  It worked out, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way is to pass iterators, not values

```
std::vector<UINT16> myvect(myarray + 3, myarray + 3 + 16);
```

Comment: Assuming size is greater than 18, else you have UB.

Comment: @SidS : :-) :-)

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> UINT16 myarray[] = { 0,1,2,3,4,5,6, ..., n };
> std::vector<UINT16> myvect(myarray[3], myarray[3] + 16);
> ```

This uses `myarray[3]` which is `3` and `myarray[3] + 16` which is `19` as arguments to the `myvect` constructor.  Which in turn sets up `myvect` to contain `3` elements, all with the value `19`.

If you want a copy of the 16 elements starting at index 3, you can do it like this:

```
std::vector<UINT16> myvect(&myarray[3], &myarray[3 + 16]);
```

Comment: Assuming size is greater than 19, else you have UB. (Where it is clear that `UINT16 myarray[7]` would produce UB, it is also the case for `UINT16 myarray[19]`).

Comment: @Jarod42, It will work if size is 19, too.  Anyway, this possible UB was present in the question and it's not what the OP was asking about.

Comment: Seems there is a debate if `&*pointer` is `pointer` or not (and so UB or not)... So I would avoid it. See [may-i-take-the-address-of-the-one-past-the-end-element-of-an-array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3144904/may-i-take-the-address-of-the-one-past-the-end-element-of-an-array).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a different (more verbose) way:

```
uint16_t       myarray[]  = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, ..., n };
constexpr auto arr_size   = sizeof(myarray) / sizeof(myarray[0]);
constexpr auto copy_start = std::min< size_t >(3, arr_size);
constexpr auto copy_count = 19;
constexpr auto copy_end   = std::min< size_t >(copy_start + copy_count, arr_size);

vector< uint16_t > myvect(std::next(myarray, copy_start), std::next(myarray, copy_end));
```

Instead of `UINT16` you can use `uint16_t` type from C++11 onwards: [Fixed width integers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer) (if your compiler supports it)

If your values are available at compile time, then you can use compile time constants(`constexpr`) to calculate the helper variables. Otherwise `const` should be used.

Standard algorithms can be used also on arrays so providing an offset to [`std::next`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/next) can be used to get the n-th element of an array.