# C++ does address exist?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

Suppose I have the following in C++:

```
char buffer[SIZE];
char * ptr = &buffer[SIZE];
```

where `ptr`'s value is never dereferenced. Is this even legal to do C++? That is use the memory address one stride from the last element of an array (say as a special value to compare to)?

Comment: Does this compile? Should it be `char * ptr = &buffer[SIZE];`?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/988158/take-the-address-of-a-one-past-the-end-array-element-via-subscript-legal-by-the

Comment: You did dereference when you said `buffer[SIZE]`... Formally it's a grey area, but FWIW no compiler I've ever seen will do anything unexpected.

Comment: @litb:  Its not a gray area.  The Standard explicitly allows taking the address, but dereferincing that address is explicitly undefined behavior.

Comment: @John But using [] does dereference it! I suppose one should really say `buffer+SIZE` instead of `&buffer[SIZE]`.

Comment: I'm not sure that it does, but I'll have to check the Std later when I get some time.

Comment: @John: this has been round a few times. The issue is that `&buffer[SIZE]` is defined to mean `&*(buffer + SIZE)`. Nothing in the standard seems to explicitly state that in this context, the `*` operator does not in fact dereference its operand. However, no lvalue-to-rvalue conversion takes place, and in practice as far as implementations are concerned that's what actually performs a memory load (aka "dereference").

Comment: @John no. He did dereference that address when he said `buffer[SIZE]`. That is equivalent to `*(buffer + SIZE)` which does dereference a pointer, yielding an lvalue. It does *not* read a value from the lvalue, but the grey area consists in that the spec is not clear on whether or not reading the read is required for it to be UB.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you said:

```
char buffer[SIZE];
char * ptr = & buffer[SIZE];
```

then yes, it is legal. You are specifically allowed by the C++ standard to use the one-past-the-end of an array in this manner, and it is used extensively when (for example) working with iterators.

**Edit:** But see comments by litb and Steve Jessop. If you want to be entirely politcally correct, you probably want:

```
char * ptr = buffer + SIZE;
```

Either way, the one-past-the-end address is a valid address - the perhaps not quite clear issue (as I understand it) is whether you are allowed to dereference it.

Comment: And in fact, many implementations of STL algorithms depend on this guarantee.

Comment: @John: which implementations of STL algorithms rely on doing `&*(ptr+offset)`? None of them deal in arrays and offsets, they deal in iterators (and hence sometimes in pointers). The address `buffer+SIZE` is definitely fine, that's explicitly dealt with in the definition of pointer addition. It's the intermediate lvalue `*(buffer+SIZE)` that's in question.

Answer (score 6):

You meant `&buffer[SIZE]`? Yes it is legal in C++. The value of ptr is one past end of buffer, most standard algorithms can use it as end() iterator for buffer.