# Intel compiler produces code 68% slower than MSVC (full example provided)

Tags: c++, performance, optimization, cpu, icc

I have C++ code processing three consecutive values from one single 1800-element array. The code compiled by ICC 14.0 is approximately 68% slower (1600 vs 2700 CPU cycles) than the code produced by the MSVC. I cannot understand why. Could somebody please help? Even when I set the Intel compiler -O3 switch it doesn't change the timing. The CPU is Ivy Bridge.

```
#include <iostream>

int main(){
        int data[1200];

        //Dummy-populate data
        for(int y=0; y<1200; y++){
            data[y] = y/2 + 7;
        }

        int counter = 0;

        //Just to repeat the test
        while(counter < 10000){

            int Accum = 0;
            long long start = 0;
            long long end = 0;
            int p = 0;

            start = __rdtsc();

            while(p < 1200){
                unsigned int level1 = data[p];  
                unsigned int factor = data[p + 1];
                Accum += (level1 * factor);
                p = p + 2;
            }

            end = __rdtsc();
            std::cout << (end - start) << "  " << Accum << std::endl;
            counter++;
        }
}
```

Comment: This went from 55% to 60% to 68% yet no code changed.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious my maths got more accurate. First was a guestimate on the %, then I calculated it and then I calculated it correctly (I think)...

Comment: I guess `__intel_new_feature_proc_init` must have a call to Sleep in it ;)

Comment: @500-InternalServerError, it still outside of measured interval. user997112, are you getting same numbers for every repeat of the test?

Comment: @osgx no there are some large outliers but about 95% of the timings are pretty close together.

Comment: @user997112: you must expect large outliers - rdtscp reads a core-specific clock counter register and BIOSs often leave them unsynced, so if you haven't bound the code to a core, get pre-empted or interrupted, the timing will be off (potentially even negative).

Comment: @user997112, try to run intel IACA (Architecture Code Analyzer), which is free to use. I have results from it for gcc/icc pair and Ivy Bridge pipeline simulated (`-arch IVB`), and tool says that icc's code: "*Block Throughput: 2.25 Cycles       Throughput Bottleneck: FrontEnd*" and gcc's code: "*Block Throughput: 1.70 Cycles       Throughput Bottleneck: InterIteration*". PS: Tony D, I think we can only search for lowest output (fastest code) and no problem with any SMMing/Virtualization of rdtscp.

Comment: @osgx I have VTune available. What difference do you see between GCC and ICC?

Comment: user997112, Vtune is hard to use monster, and linux's perf is easier to use. I have only early "Core 2" cpu, so can't run real test for Ivy. My best results are 2450 for icc 14 and 2150 for gcc4.8.2. And Intel IACA is pipeline simulator, the unique tool, which was not integrated in Vtune last time I checked. PS: IACA may not support `imul` for IVB pipeline simulator and will underestimate clock cycles.

Comment: I wonder if making this SIMD-friendly would improve performance. E.g., rather than including factor in the same array, put it in a separate array with each value repeated and use four accumulators. Since this is a streaming operation, memory bandwidth would probably limit performance in real use—duplicating `factor` introduces 33% data bloat (in the benchmark it should help). Compilers probably would not recognize the ability to use a permute instruction to duplicate `factor` in register, just as they did not recognize the ability to use separate partial accumulators.

Comment: You did not provide the full command lines for both compilers, it might help. Also playing with target cpu specification might help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ICC sucks here because it's working out the addresses for each `data[n]` access ala `mov edi,dword ptr [rsp+rax*4+44h]`... all that run-time multiplication is expensive.  You should be able to avoid it by recoding so the indices are constants (could also use `*p_data++` three times, but that introduces a sequencing issue that may adversely affect performance).

```
for (unsigned* p_data = &data[0], *p_end = data + 1800; p_data < p_end; p_data += 3)
{
    unsigned level1 = p_data[0];
    unsigned level2 = p_data[1];
    unsigned factor = p_data[2];

    Accum1 += level1 * factor;
    Accum2 += level2 * factor;
}
```

Comment: I tried having three separate unsigned short offsets, initilized to 0, 1 and 2 and then after each loop incrementing all of them by 3, this breaks dependencies but it didn't speed up the ICC code :(

It did speed up the MSVC code!

Comment: I am getting compiler errors for the suggestion. Did you mean to put unsigned int* at the beginning? The compiler errors are on the ampersand in "&data[1800]" and the "<" in "p_data < p_end"

Comment: `unsigned *p_data, *p_end`.  The answer is missing the second `*`.

Comment: @MooingDuck: And what about `1[&data]` ?  It's an lvalue to an array that doesn't exist, which decays to the past-the-end pointer for `data`.

Comment: @MooingDuck: I wasn't making an argument, just wanted to know if you think that is a reasonable way to write it.

Comment: Also, is `auto p_data = data;` the same as `auto p_data = &data[0];`?

Comment: @MooingDuck: 5.7/5 "If both the pointer operand and the result point to elements of the same array object, or **one past
the last element of the array object**, the evaluation shall not produce an overflow" - looks ok to me... any links to the debate?

Comment: @TonyD: The problem is that your expression is `&*(data + 1800)` and mine is `*(1 + &data)` and both dereference an off-the-end pointer (but don't allow lvalue->rvalue conversion)

Comment: @TonyD: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/988158/take-the-address-of-a-one-past-the-end-array-element-via-subscript-legal-by-the  The problem isn't having a _pointer_ to one past the end, it's the fact that you have a _reference_ to the one past the end.

Comment: @user997112: "I tried..." - that still leaves the indices to be multiplied out at compile time.  Have you tried my code with the extra `*` before `p_end`?

Comment: ICC now about 10-15% slower. I'll post the asm in my question.

Comment: @user997112: 10-15% slower than MSVC, or 10-15% slower than the earlier ICC code?  Either way, might be worth quickly trying `= *p_data++` three times (and removing `p_data += 3`).

Comment: MSVC is giving me 1400-1500 CPU cycles. ICC is now giving me 1650 CPU cycles after implementing your suggestion.

Comment: @MooingDuck: ok - interesting discussion though I can't imagine any compiler would let it break... I'll update accordingly.  Cheers.

Comment: @user997112: fair enough... personally I don't think you can reasonably expect much better - optimisers take different approaches and must be expected to vary in output quality.  If you really care, you could try more variations (`*pdata++`...?), use inline assembly, link in the MSVC output, enable the compiler loop unwinding optimisation (may have more impact anyway).  If `factor` is known to only have a few values (e.g. always 1 or 2) you may be able to optimise for those ala `level1 << (factor-1)`.

Answer (score 1):

user997112, I tested your new code (only one level and accum), and I get only 5% difference between gcc and icc with `-O3` option (`-march=native -mtune=native` may help you). I have Core 2 Q6600 fixed on 2.4 GHz, best results are 1800 for gcc and 1900 for icc.

Here is my version of test (`rdtsc()` redefined with gnu asm, runtimes are saved in array, and only minimal (best) runtime is printed:

```
$ cat my.cc
#include <iostream>

#if 1
// my cpu has no rdtscp, so use asm
inline unsigned long long rdtsc() __attribute__((always_inline));
inline unsigned long long rdtsc() {
  unsigned int lo, hi;
  asm volatile (
     "cpuid \n"
     "rdtsc" 
   : "=a"(lo), "=d"(hi) /* outputs */
   : "a"(0)             /* inputs */
   : "%ebx", "%ecx");     /* clobbers*/
  return ((unsigned long long)lo) | (((unsigned long long)hi) << 32);
}
#else
#define rdtsc __rdtsc
#endif

int main(){
        int data[1200];
        int dummy[10000];
        int stats[10000];

        //Dummy-populate data
        for(int y=0; y<1200; y++){
            data[y] = y/2 + 7;
        }
        for(int y=0; y<10000; y++){
            stats[y]=0;
        }

        int counter = 0;

        //Just to repeat the test
        while(counter < 10000){

            int Accum = 0;
            long long start = 0;
            long long end = 0;
            int p = 0;

            start = rdtsc();

            while(p < 1200){
                unsigned int level1 = data[p];  
                unsigned int factor = data[p + 1];
                Accum += (level1 * factor);
                p = p + 2;
            }

            end = rdtsc();
            stats[counter]=(end - start);
            dummy[counter]=Accum;
            counter++;
        }

        int min=0xfffff;
        for(int y=0; y<10000; y++) {
            if(stats[y] < min) {
                min = stats[y];
                std::cout << min << std::endl;
                std::cout << "accum " << dummy[y] << std::endl;
            }
        }
        std::cout << min << std::endl;
}
```

Compiled with icc 14 and gcc 4.8 as:

```
$ g++ my.cc -o mygccO3t -O3 -march=native -mtune=native
$ icc my.cc -o myiccO3t -O3 -march=native -mtune=native
```

Results (CPU frequency changing is disabled at 2.4 GHz, core is fixed by `taskset`, measured by Linux PMU access tool [`perf`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perf_%28Linux%29)):

```
$ taskset -c 3 perf stat -e cycles:u,instructions:u ./myiccO3t |tail -n 1 
 Performance counter stats for './myiccO3t':
    23 875 260 cycles:u                 
    28 866 440 instructions:u            #    1,21  insns per cycle        

   0,011297567 seconds time elapsed
1899

$ taskset -c 3 perf stat -e cycles:u,instructions:u ./mygccO3t |tail -n 1 
 Performance counter stats for './mygccO3t':
    22 389 238 cycles:u                 
    43 551 129 instructions:u            #    1,95  insns per cycle        

   0,010683920 seconds time elapsed
1800
```

So, we can see, that gcc needs much more instructions to handle same amount of data, but also it achieves better IPC (instruction per clock) rate.

There is simple assembler code for inner loop from gcc:

```
  4009b9:       45 31 c0                xor    %r8d,%r8d
  4009bc:       45 31 c9                xor    %r9d,%r9d
  4009bf:       90                      nop
  4009c0:       44 89 c8                mov    %r9d,%eax
  4009c3:       0f a2                   cpuid  
  4009c5:       0f 31                   rdtsc  
  4009c7:       49 89 d2                mov    %rdx,%r10
  4009ca:       89 c0                   mov    %eax,%eax
  4009cc:       48 89 e2                mov    %rsp,%rdx
  4009cf:       49 c1 e2 20             shl    $0x20,%r10
  4009d3:       31 ff                   xor    %edi,%edi
  4009d5:       49 09 c2                or     %rax,%r10
  4009d8:       0f 1f 84 00 00 00 00    nopl   0x0(%rax,%rax,1)
  4009df:       00 

   vvvv
  4009e0:       8b 4a 04                mov    0x4(%rdx),%ecx
  4009e3:       48 83 c2 08             add    $0x8,%rdx
  4009e7:       0f af 4a f8             imul   -0x8(%rdx),%ecx
  4009eb:       48 39 d5                cmp    %rdx,%rbp
  4009ee:       8d 34 39                lea    (%rcx,%rdi,1),%esi
  4009f1:       89 f7                   mov    %esi,%edi
  4009f3:       75 eb                   jne    4009e0 <main+0x90>
   ^^^^

  4009f5:       44 89 c8                mov    %r9d,%eax
  4009f8:       0f a2                   cpuid  
  4009fa:       0f 31                   rdtsc
```

And heavy SSE2/unroll from icc (part of loop, 1184 iterations, was vectorized, and tail is handled after loop):

```
  400e4c:       33 c9                   xor    %ecx,%ecx
  400e4e:       49 89 cd                mov    %rcx,%r13
  400e51:       33 c0                   xor    %eax,%eax
  400e53:       0f a2                   cpuid  
  400e55:       0f 31                   rdtsc  
  400e57:       66 0f ef c9             pxor   %xmm1,%xmm1
  400e5b:       66 0f 6f 05 7d 2f 00    movdqa 0x2f7d(%rip),%xmm0         
  400e62:       00 
  400e63:       41 89 c4                mov    %eax,%r12d
  400e66:       33 c0                   xor    %eax,%eax

   vvvv
  400e68:       66 0f 6f 9c c4 80 38    movdqa 0x13880(%rsp,%rax,8),%xmm3
  400e6f:       01 00 
  400e71:       66 0f 6f 94 c4 90 38    movdqa 0x13890(%rsp,%rax,8),%xmm2
  400e78:       01 00 
  400e7a:       66 0f 6f f3             movdqa %xmm3,%xmm6
  400e7e:       66 0f 62 f2             punpckldq %xmm2,%xmm6
  400e82:       66 0f 6a da             punpckhdq %xmm2,%xmm3
  400e86:       66 0f 6f fe             movdqa %xmm6,%xmm7
  400e8a:       66 0f 62 fb             punpckldq %xmm3,%xmm7
  400e8e:       66 0f 6f ac c4 a0 38    movdqa 0x138a0(%rsp,%rax,8),%xmm5
  400e95:       01 00 
  400e97:       66 44 0f 6f d7          movdqa %xmm7,%xmm10
  400e9c:       66 0f 6a f3             punpckhdq %xmm3,%xmm6
  400ea0:       66 44 0f 6f c5          movdqa %xmm5,%xmm8
  400ea5:       66 0f 6f a4 c4 b0 38    movdqa 0x138b0(%rsp,%rax,8),%xmm4
  400eac:       01 00 
  400eae:       66 0f 73 d7 20          psrlq  $0x20,%xmm7
  400eb3:       66 44 0f f4 d6          pmuludq %xmm6,%xmm10
  400eb8:       66 0f 73 d6 20          psrlq  $0x20,%xmm6
  400ebd:       66 0f f4 fe             pmuludq %xmm6,%xmm7
  400ec1:       66 44 0f 6f ac c4 c0    movdqa 0x138c0(%rsp,%rax,8),%xmm13
  400ec8:       38 01 00 
  400ecb:       66 44 0f db d0          pand   %xmm0,%xmm10
  400ed0:       66 44 0f 62 c4          punpckldq %xmm4,%xmm8
  400ed5:       66 45 0f 6f f5          movdqa %xmm13,%xmm14
  400eda:       66 44 0f 6f a4 c4 d0    movdqa 0x138d0(%rsp,%rax,8),%xmm12
  400ee1:       38 01 00 
  400ee4:       66 45 0f 6f c8          movdqa %xmm8,%xmm9
  400ee9:       66 0f 6a ec             punpckhdq %xmm4,%xmm5
  400eed:       66 0f 73 f7 20          psllq  $0x20,%xmm7
  400ef2:       66 0f 6f a4 c4 e0 38    movdqa 0x138e0(%rsp,%rax,8),%xmm4
  400ef9:       01 00 
  400efb:       66 44 0f eb d7          por    %xmm7,%xmm10
  400f00:       66 0f 6f 9c c4 f0 38    movdqa 0x138f0(%rsp,%rax,8),%xmm3
  400f07:       01 00 
  400f09:       66 41 0f fe ca          paddd  %xmm10,%xmm1
  400f0e:       66 44 0f 62 cd          punpckldq %xmm5,%xmm9
  400f13:       48 83 c0 10             add    $0x10,%rax
  400f17:       66 44 0f 6a c5          punpckhdq %xmm5,%xmm8
  400f1c:       66 0f 6f ec             movdqa %xmm4,%xmm5
  400f20:       66 45 0f 62 f4          punpckldq %xmm12,%xmm14
  400f25:       66 45 0f 6f d9          movdqa %xmm9,%xmm11
  400f2a:       66 45 0f 6a ec          punpckhdq %xmm12,%xmm13
  400f2f:       66 45 0f 6f fe          movdqa %xmm14,%xmm15
  400f34:       66 0f 62 eb             punpckldq %xmm3,%xmm5
  400f38:       66 41 0f 73 d1 20       psrlq  $0x20,%xmm9
  400f3e:       66 45 0f 62 fd          punpckldq %xmm13,%xmm15
  400f43:       66 0f 6f f5             movdqa %xmm5,%xmm6
  400f47:       66 0f 6a e3             punpckhdq %xmm3,%xmm4
  400f4b:       66 41 0f 6f d7          movdqa %xmm15,%xmm2
  400f50:       66 45 0f f4 d8          pmuludq %xmm8,%xmm11
  400f55:       66 41 0f 73 d0 20       psrlq  $0x20,%xmm8
  400f5b:       66 45 0f f4 c8          pmuludq %xmm8,%xmm9
  400f60:       66 45 0f 6a f5          punpckhdq %xmm13,%xmm14
  400f65:       66 41 0f 73 d7 20       psrlq  $0x20,%xmm15
  400f6b:       66 0f 62 f4             punpckldq %xmm4,%xmm6
  400f6f:       66 44 0f db d8          pand   %xmm0,%xmm11
  400f74:       66 41 0f f4 d6          pmuludq %xmm14,%xmm2
  400f79:       66 41 0f 73 d6 20       psrlq  $0x20,%xmm14
  400f7f:       66 45 0f f4 fe          pmuludq %xmm14,%xmm15
  400f84:       66 0f 6a ec             punpckhdq %xmm4,%xmm5
  400f88:       66 0f 6f fe             movdqa %xmm6,%xmm7
  400f8c:       66 0f f4 fd             pmuludq %xmm5,%xmm7
  400f90:       66 0f 73 d6 20          psrlq  $0x20,%xmm6
  400f95:       66 0f 73 d5 20          psrlq  $0x20,%xmm5
  400f9a:       66 41 0f 73 f1 20       psllq  $0x20,%xmm9
  400fa0:       66 0f f4 f5             pmuludq %xmm5,%xmm6
  400fa4:       66 45 0f eb d9          por    %xmm9,%xmm11
  400fa9:       66 0f db d0             pand   %xmm0,%xmm2
  400fad:       66 41 0f 73 f7 20       psllq  $0x20,%xmm15
  400fb3:       66 41 0f fe cb          paddd  %xmm11,%xmm1
  400fb8:       66 41 0f eb d7          por    %xmm15,%xmm2
  400fbd:       66 0f db f8             pand   %xmm0,%xmm7
  400fc1:       66 0f 73 f6 20          psllq  $0x20,%xmm6
  400fc6:       66 0f fe ca             paddd  %xmm2,%xmm1
  400fca:       66 0f eb fe             por    %xmm6,%xmm7
  400fce:       66 0f fe cf             paddd  %xmm7,%xmm1
  400fd2:       48 3d 50 02 00 00       cmp    $0x250,%rax
  400fd8:       0f 82 8a fe ff ff       jb     400e68 <main+0xe8>
   ^^^^

  400fde:       66 0f 6f c1             movdqa %xmm1,%xmm0
  400fe2:       66 0f 73 d8 08          psrldq $0x8,%xmm0
  400fe7:       66 0f fe c8             paddd  %xmm0,%xmm1
  400feb:       66 0f 6f d1             movdqa %xmm1,%xmm2
  400fef:       8b 84 24 00 4b 01 00    mov    0x14b00(%rsp),%eax
  400ff6:       66 0f 73 d2 20          psrlq  $0x20,%xmm2
  400ffb:       0f af 84 24 04 4b 01    imul   0x14b04(%rsp),%eax
  401002:       00 
  401003:       66 0f fe ca             paddd  %xmm2,%xmm1
  401007:       66 0f 7e cb             movd   %xmm1,%ebx
  40100b:       8b 94 24 08 4b 01 00    mov    0x14b08(%rsp),%edx
  401012:       03 d8                   add    %eax,%ebx
  401014:       0f af 94 24 0c 4b 01    imul   0x14b0c(%rsp),%edx
  40101b:       00 
  40101c:       8b b4 24 10 4b 01 00    mov    0x14b10(%rsp),%esi
  401023:       03 da                   add    %edx,%ebx
  401025:       0f af b4 24 14 4b 01    imul   0x14b14(%rsp),%esi
  40102c:       00 
  40102d:       8b bc 24 18 4b 01 00    mov    0x14b18(%rsp),%edi
  401034:       03 de                   add    %esi,%ebx
  401036:       0f af bc 24 1c 4b 01    imul   0x14b1c(%rsp),%edi
  40103d:       00 
  40103e:       44 8b 84 24 20 4b 01    mov    0x14b20(%rsp),%r8d
  401045:       00 
  401046:       03 df                   add    %edi,%ebx
  401048:       44 0f af 84 24 24 4b    imul   0x14b24(%rsp),%r8d
  40104f:       01 00 
  401051:       44 8b 8c 24 28 4b 01    mov    0x14b28(%rsp),%r9d
  401058:       00 
  401059:       41 03 d8                add    %r8d,%ebx
  40105c:       44 0f af 8c 24 2c 4b    imul   0x14b2c(%rsp),%r9d
  401063:       01 00 
  401065:       44 8b 94 24 30 4b 01    mov    0x14b30(%rsp),%r10d
  40106c:       00 
  40106d:       41 03 d9                add    %r9d,%ebx
  401070:       44 0f af 94 24 34 4b    imul   0x14b34(%rsp),%r10d
  401077:       01 00 
  401079:       44 8b 9c 24 38 4b 01    mov    0x14b38(%rsp),%r11d
  401080:       00 
  401081:       41 03 da                add    %r10d,%ebx
  401084:       44 0f af 9c 24 3c 4b    imul   0x14b3c(%rsp),%r11d
  40108b:       01 00 
  40108d:       41 03 db                add    %r11d,%ebx
  401090:       e8 eb 00 00 00          callq  401180 <_Z5rdtscv>
```