# Why does std::accumulate behave like this with standard arrays?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, c++11

I'm just getting into C++ and I think I have a handle on pointers, but `std::accumulate()` has me confused.

Given the array:

```
int a[3] = { 5, 6, 7 };
```

I'd like to sum the values of the array with `std::accumulate()`, so I pass it a pointer to the first element, then the last, then the starting value of the accumulator.

```
std::accumulate(a, a + 2, 0);
std::accumulate(&a[0], &a[2], 0);
```

Oops: either of these returns the sum of only the first two elements: `11`.

On the other hand, if the second argument is a nonsensical pointer, just out of bounds...

```
std::accumulate(a, a + 3, 0);
std::accumulate(&a[0], &a[3], 0);
```

... the correct value of `18` is returned.

Could someone please explain this? I realise that I could avoid using simple arrays, but that's beside the point.

Comment: [Here's Dijkstra](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?WhyNumberingShouldStartAtZero) on why half-open range is best range.

Comment: The second parameter to `std::accumulate` is the iterator position of the first element to **not** include in the accumulation. Can't put it simpler than that.

Comment: `&a[3]` is undefined behaviour. `a + 3` is not.

Comment: @chris [no, `&a[N]` is not UB](http://stackoverflow.com/q/988158/819272)

Comment: @TemplateRex the top answer to that question doesn't correctly establish lack of UB, he gets to the end and then does some hand-waving.  Still unanswered is whether `&*(a+3)` counts as dereferencing the pointer `a+3`, and if it does; then whether it is UB to dereference `a+3` .

Comment: Whether or not this case turns out to be UB, it's still a bad pattern to use because it certainly can be UB if `a` were a class type (e.g. `std::vector`)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

C++ ranges are defined as `[first, last)`, and all the STL algorithm work like that. In this case, `std::accumulate` sums up all the elements behind the iterator-defined range, starting with `first` and ending at `last` without actually dereferencing it.

Thus, calling it like `std::accumulate(a, a+3, 0)` is actually correct and equal to calling it with `std::accumulate(begin(a), end(a), 0)`.

Also note that this doesn't fall foul of the "no pointers to outside of allocated arrays" rule, as there is a specific exception for pointer to just behind the last element.

Comment: This is necessary to handle the degenerate case where you want to operate on zero elements. There's a special exception for a pointer just beyond the last element, but no such exception for a pointer just ahead of the first element.

Answer (score 5):

`std::accumulate`, like most STL algorithms, takes an iterator past the last element of the container. In this case, that iterator would be `&a[3]`. You might want to use `std::begin()`, `std::end()` since it works with all containers and is less error-prone. Also, since `std::begin` on arrays is just a pointer you can always say things like `std::begin()+k`. So, you don't lose any flexibility.

Comment: Or more simply `a + 3`

Comment: I'd rather say, "since std::begin on arrays is a RandomAccessIterator, you can always say things like std::begin()+k". Nobody said std::begin() on array must be a pointer, i think

Comment: @gigabytes, The standard gives the following declarationfor `std::begin` on arrays: `template <class T, size_t N> T* begin(T (&array)[N]);`

Answer (score 2):

The end iterator is one past the last element since "ranges" are half open in the stl. This means that the first element is included and the last one is NOT included.

Besides that, I recommend you to use c++11 begin and end free functions. They are overloaded for plain c arrays as well.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know the historical reason of this convention for iterators (including raw pointers and STL Iterators). But my opinion is it is consistent to the way we access arrays or containers with index.

1.

C/C++ array and C++ STL containers count the index from 0 to (size - 1).

Consider what will happen when you calculate the size of the array or container by taking the difference between a pair of pointers or iterators like:

```
size = ending_pointer - beginning_pointer;
// or
size = std::distance(beginning_iterator, ending_iterator);
```

This will really give you the size if ending_pointer or ending_iterator refers to the position past-the-last.

2.

Conventionally, looping through an array with index like this:

```
for (size_t i = 0 ; i < size ; ++i)
```

Note that we use less-than instead of less-than-or-equal-to.

For iterator:

```
// Usually found in implementations of STL algorithms
for (iterator_type it = beginning_iterator ; it != ending_iterator ; ++it)
```

Note that we use not-equal-to instead of equal-to.

3.

To handle the cases with an array or container of size 0, the convention of one-position-past-the-last is convenient for programmers and compiler optimization, since the beginning iterator will be equal to ending iterator.

```
for (iterator_type it = beginning_iterator ; it != ending_iterator_which_equals_the_beginning ; ++it)
// still consistent to
for (size_t i = 0 ; i < size_which_is_zero ; ++i)
```

---

As mentioned in others' answers, we prefer `std::begin(container)` and `std::end(container)`. They can free us from the troubles of pointer arithmetic and thus less error prone. They also make generic coding easier.

Answer (score 1):

`std::accumulate(...)` usually is better use with `std::begin(...)` and `std::end(...)` functions. According a code `std::accumulate(first, last, 0)` it sums up elements from `first` to `last`, but without the `last` one. When you are using container methods `begin()`, `end()` code sums up every elements (as you expect) because `end()` returns iterator to past-the-end element (element after the last true element). It is used for example in loops:

```
vector<int> vec = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 };

for (auto it = begin(vec); it != end(vec); ++it)
{
    // do some work ...
}
```

Functions `std::begin(...)` and `std::end(...)` work with simple C++ array.
Your code with `&a[3]` works because you point to the next element after the true last one. But your code is not correct and you mustn't code like that.