# Vector initialization using array

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

we can initialize a vector using array. suppose,

```
int a[]={1,2,3}
vector<int>x(a,a+3)
```

this is a way . My question is, what is `a` and `a+3` here, are they pointer?

and someone could explain this:
for the above array

```
vector<int>x(a,&a[3])
```

also gives no error and do the same as above code. If we write a[3], it should be outside of the array? can someone tell me the inner mechanism?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Take the address of a one-past-the-end array element via subscript: legal by the C++ Standard or not?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/988158/take-the-address-of-a-one-past-the-end-array-element-via-subscript-legal-by-the)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, `a` and `a+3` are pointers.  The plain `a` is an array that gets converted implicitly to a pointer at the drop of a hat.

The construct `&a[3]` is identical in meaning to `a+3` for plain C arrays.  Yes, `a[3]` is outside the array, but one-past is allowed to *point to*, if you don't *dereference* it.

Answer (score 0):

A vector's range constructor looks like this:

```
template <class InputIterator>
         vector (InputIterator first, InputIterator last,
                 const allocator_type& alloc = allocator_type());
```

It will construct elements in the range `[first, last)`, meaning that the last element is not included. `&a[3]` points to an element outside the bounds of the array, similar to how `std::end(a)` will point one past the end of `a`. Compare it to:

```
std::vector<int> x(std::begin(a), std::end(a));
```

Also, `*(a + 3)` is equivalent to `a[3]`.

Answer (score 0):

int a[]={1,2,3}

vectorx(a,a+3)

a is an array so it is always pointing to its base address. 
a+3 mean base address+(sizeof(int) *3)

suppose base address is 100
 a=100;
 a+3=106;

Answer (score 0):

vectorx(a,&a[3])

Here &a[3] is equivalent to a+3