# Pointer to an array,why is this the address of the last element?

Tags: c++, pointers

I am working with tutorials point.com example.

```
int  var[MAX] = {10, 100, 200};
int  *ptr;

// let us have address of the last element in pointer.
ptr = &var[MAX-1];
for (int i = MAX; i > 0; i--)
{
    cout << "Address of var[" << i << "] = ";
    cout << ptr << endl;

    cout << "Value of var[" << i << "] = ";
    cout << *ptr << endl;

    // point to the previous location
    ptr--;
}
return 0;
```

So, why `&var[MAX - 1]`  and why not `&var[MAX]`? If we do not use a reference, would it be possible to solve this problem in a different manner?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because arrays in C++ are zero-based, i.e. start from `0` and end at `n-1`. `var[MAX]` is the element past the end of the array, so is out-of-bounds and accessing it is undefined behaviour.

```
var   { 10, 100, 200 }
index   ^0  ^1^  ^2^   ^3?
```

Comment: not *accessing* it, but [you **can** have a pointer to it](http://stackoverflow.com/a/988220/2297448) as long as you don't dereference it.